# Eclipse development - getting the number of currently shown lines in editor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, editor, lines

I would like to get the information about the currently shown lines in editor inside Eclipse IDE:

[image]

The editor shows 16 lines, but the hw1.c has 30 lines.

So far I was able to get the total number of lines of the document by calling:

```
reference.getEditor(false).getDocumentProvider().getDocument(
    reference.getEditor(false).getEditorInput()).getNumberOfLines()
```

But this call always returns the **total** number of lines (i.e. 30 for the sample).

Is there a way how the get the number of **currently** shown lines (i.e. 16 for the sample)? I checked the `IDocument` interface but did not find any method for this.

I also need to get updated each time the showing lines changed.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't easy to get outside of the actual editor. You really want the `ITextViewer` so you can call `getTopIndex` and `getBottomIndex` but there is no way to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to check how many LOC you have written ? If so, have a look at this:

http://metrics.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I am trying to figure out how many lines of the file is shown to the user, not the total lines - I am able to get LOC from the `reference.getEditor(false).getDocumentProvider().getDocument(reference.getEditor(false).getEditorInput()).getNumberOfLines()`.